# I need to convert the code from flask_sqlalchemy ORM to raw SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables: User, Posts and association table - Followers.

I am creating a subscriber system in my project (Social Network) and for the sake of speed I want to write instead of this function:

```
def followed_posts_by_user(self):
    followed_posts = Post.query.join(
        followers, (followers.c.followed_id == Post.user_id)).filter(
            followers.c.follower_id == self.id)
    filtered = Post.query.filter_by(user_id=self.id)

    return followed_posts.union(filtered).order_by(Posts.timestamp.desc())
```

A raw SQL because this function seems too complex, I wrote this code

```
  comm = """
                    SELECT * from posts
                    INNER JOIN followers
                    ON followers.followed_id=posts.user_id

                    WHERE followers.follower_id = '(%s)';
            """
            cursor.execute(comm, self.id)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: *"But it doesn't work."* means what exactly? What error did you get? Looks like your parameter shouldn't be in quotes

Comment: It's not a syntax error, I was getting NoneType during the tests. In the tests I'm creating users, posts and make follow, after that I'm trying to get all posts from someone and getting NoneType error.

Comment: @QualcommAtheros Because there should not be quotes around parameter since the parameter placeholder substitutes *the data*, not some text in your SQL statement. So, `'(%s)'` is a string literal with value `(%s)`, while `follower_id = (%s)` is essentially filters by the passed parameter value (included in brackets which do nothing). Check [PEP-249 paramstyle paragraph](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) for examples of parameter passing and choose the one your DB module uses.

Comment: @astentx Okay. I removed quotes. I'm getting syntax error and still getting another error - Nonetype object.